# Oracle dynamic parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm struggling to create a dynamic sql parametrized query. It involves using 'IS NULL' or 'IS NOT NULL'

Here's a simple pl/sql query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_ALL_INFORMATION 
(
  "PARAM_START_DATE" IN DATE,
  "PARAM_END_DATE" IN DATE,
  "PARAM_IS_SUBMITTED" IN NUMBER,
  "EXTRACT_SUBMITTED_CONTACTS" OUT sys_refcursor
) IS

sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(3000);
PARAM_CONDITION VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

IF PARAM_IS_SUBMITTED = 1 THEN
     PARAM_CONDITION := 'NOT NULL'; 
    ELSE
     PARAM_CONDITION :=  'NULL';
  END IF;

  sql_stmt := ' SELECT
  REGISTRATION_NUMBER,
  NAME PROVIDER_TYPE,
  ORGANIZATION
  FROM TABLE_A 
  WHERE
  P.DATE_FINALIZED IS :A;

  OPEN EXTRACT_SUBMITTED_CONTACTS FOR sql_stmt USING PARAM_CONDITION;
```

Whereas the parameter (:A) in (USING PARAM_CONDITION) should have 'NULL' or 'NOT NULL'. It does not seem to work the way I envisioned.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Bind parameters can't be used in that fashion. Also, you seem to be missing a closing single-quote. If you're going to use dynamic SQL, just create your string value to directly contain the `is null` or `is not null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by *GriffeyDog* in a comment above, *bind* parameters could only be used as place holder for *values*. Not to replace keywords or identifiers.

However, this is not really an issue here, as you are using *dynamic SQL*. The key idea ifs that you build your query as a *string* -- and it will be parsed at run-time by the PL/SQL engine when you invoke `EXECUTE` or `OPEN .. FOR`.

Simply said, you need a concatenation -- not a bound parameter:

```
  ...
  sql_stmt := ' SELECT
  REGISTRATION_NUMBER,
  NAME PROVIDER_TYPE,
  ORGANIZATION
  FROM TABLE_A 
  WHERE
  P.DATE_FINALIZED IS ' || PARAM_CONDITION;
  --                    ^^

  OPEN EXTRACT_SUBMITTED_CONTACTS FOR sql_stmt;
```